# database question

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, cursor

I have written the bellow cursor :

```
declare myCursor cursor 
  for select productID, productName from products
 declare @productID int 
 declare @productName nvarchar(50)

  open myCursor
  fetch next from myCursor into @productID,@productName
 print @productID
 print @productName
 set @productID=0
  set @productName=''

  while @@FETCH_STATUS=0
  begin
    fetch next from myCursor into @productID,@productName
    print @productID
    print @productName
    set @productID=0
    set @productName=''

  end
 close myCursor
 deallocate myCursor
```

I want it to have another column named RowNomber which display the number of each row while executing the cursor. Should I declare another varriabl equal with 1 and plus it with 1 ( +1) in the begin-end block? Is there any beter way to do it?
( i am using sql server 2008)

Comment: Incidentally, you might get more views/answers if you title your question something more specific than just "database question".

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is probably as you suggest.

An alternative would be to add it to the `select` statement as follows

```
select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by (select 0)) As Rownumber,
    productID, productName from products
```

Answer (score 0):

Incrementing a local variable would be fine.

Another option would be to use the [ROW_NUMBER() ranking function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) in your SELECT. Something like this:

```
select productID, productName
     , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY productID) AS rownum 
  from products
```

Comment: This wouldn't necessarily return the right results. There is no `order by` on the main query so there is no guarantee that the rows will actually be returned in order of `productID`